# How do you access an element by its attributes value using XSL transforms and XML?

Tags: xslt

I gave current XML:

```
<element group="personalData" groupLabel="Сведения о личных данных" index="1" integrator-define="false" label="Фамилия" name="surname" type="textbox">FFF</element>
  <element group="personalData" groupLabel="Сведения о личных данных" index="2" integrator-define="false" label="Имя" name="name" type="textbox">SSS</element>
  <element group="personalData" groupLabel="Сведения о личных данных" index="3" integrator-define="false" label="Отчество" name="surname" type="textbox">KKK</element>
```

I want to access the value from the element where group="personalData" AND index="1", using XSL transformation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your "current XML" is a snippet taken out of context - and XSLT is very much context-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<xsl:value-of select="element[@group='personalData' and @index='1']"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be something like, 'data' should be replaced with the xpath to the xml nodes.

`<xsl:value-of select="data[@group='personalData'] and data[@index='1']">`

Comment: Nope, it doesn`t work, it outputs "true" or "false",not value

Comment: Perhaps you could pass the result in a template '<xsl:template match.... ' and then get the value of the item in the template

Comment: I don't normally downvote without saying why, but it's hard to give any criticism of this answer except to say that it's totally wrong in every possible way.